# [FireDAC][Phys][SQLite] ERROR: near "(": syntax error

Tags: sql, sqlite, delphi, firedac

I encountered this problem when moving the query to FireDAC Query

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY Men7a_Row) AS RowNum,
       Nom_Prénom,
       Compte AS [Compte::Varchar(10)],
       Men7a_Value,
       Men7a_Date
  FROM R1
 WHERE Men7a_Date BETWEEN :DS AND :DF
 LIMIT 25 OFFSET 25;
```

Line problem

`row_number() OVER (ORDER BY Men7a_Row)`

Error

`[FireDAC][Phys][SQLite] ERROR: near "(": syntax error.`

Comment: Probably your version of SQLite is not 3.25+ when window functions were introduced.

Comment: SQLite version 3.33

Comment: The query is working correctly in SQliteStudio

Comment: Run `select sqlite_version()` and check the result in your app, not in SQLiteStudio.

Comment: I set it in FireDAC Query From Delphi app

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
In my case I was running a 32-bit program and had to change the EngineLinkage property in the FDPhysSQLiteDriverLink component to slDynamic and reference a 32-bit version of sqlite3.dll in the VendorLib property of that same FD component.
After that, no more syntax errors!!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).